# Google OAuth won't accept its own client_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, oauth-2.0, omniauth, google-oauth

I have an app that already successfully uses google oauth, but now I am trying to setup a staging deployment.  It is a rails app with devise and omniauth, but I think there might be a problem with how I configured Google.

In the google api admin panel (https://code.google.com/apis/console) I can see the existing app.  I created another one with a different callback url (because it is staging).  Using Postman (a fancy way to edit the url parameters) I can send a get request to google with the current production client_id and redirect_url and it works fine. When I copy and paste in the new clients (staging's) client_id and redirect_url I always get the error `Error: invalid_client`.

I'm sure where to start with trying to the figure out the problem, but I've tried a lot of different steps, renaming the urls, changing the client secret, or recreating the client in the admin panel.  Any ideas?  This error is rather cryptic.

Comment: Hello,

Could you tell us what your client id is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a temporary issue with a small set of client ids. The issue should be resolved. If you are still having problems please follow up.

Comment: I did nothing to resolve this, but suddenly they started to work. I think google knew of the issue

Comment: I have the same error, after entering the user_code and proceeding, I get `invalid_client: no support email Error 400`. Is this the same issue? How/When can this be solved?